# Copy to clipboard by Notification Action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am trying to do a Notification Action (for Android 4.1+) that will copy some text to the clipboard.
I read the reference about the Copy-Paste feature and now I have this:

```
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text","Hello, World!");
```

I don't know how to put it into an Intent that will be put into a PendingIntent.

If you can give me some example and explain it -  it will be great! I'm a new with android developing.
Thank you in advance.

*Edit:*
I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12601766/1866009 but I don't understand it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this tutorial about android notifications actions :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

when creating the pendingIntent ,  give it a custom intent that will be received by your broadcastReceiver (defined in your manifest, example [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) ) , and then do whatever you wish with it (for example copy to the clipboard) .

Comment: Thank you very much! I read these tutorials and solved my problem!

Answer (score 8):

With [android developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293006/1866009)'s help the problem was solved by this code:

```
        BroadcastReceiver brCopy = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "text");
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.ACTION_COPY");
    mContext.registerReceiver(brCopy, intentFilter);

    Intent copy = new Intent("com.example.ACTION_COPY");
    PendingIntent piCopy = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, copy, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_copy, "Copy", piCopy);
```

Comment: you could have put it on the question itself , with a horizontal divider . :)

Comment: Aside: users here are encouraged to add their own answers, and generally discouraged from editing solutions retrospectively into their question. For future readers, it is much better to read a question how it was originally asked (with appropriate improvements) and then finding answers below. This improves the quality of the data carried by the API too. +1 to Dennis.